# What is the use of len function in the below code? It also works without len function

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am practicing Python. I found this below code from a website. I understood all the code except len function which holds the size of the list. I tried this code in different way, And It worked without len function. I just want to know what the use of len function here in the below code

This is the code from a website

````
    def swapList(newList):
        size = len(newList)
    
        temp = newList[0]
        newList[0] = newList[size - 1]
        newList[size - 1] = temp

    return newList
    

newList = [12, 35, 9, 56, 24]
print(swapList(newList))`
```
````

output - [24, 35, 9, 56, 12]

*The above code worked fine.*

**This is the code that I wrote myself**

```
    temp = numbers[0]
    numbers[0] = numbers[-1]
    numbers[-1] = temp
    return numbers


numbers = [12, 15, 18, 21, 24]
print(swapping(numbers))
```

output - [24, 35, 9, 56, 12]

*This also works fine*

Comment: `len()` Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may be a sequence (such as a string, bytes, tuple, list, or range) or a collection (such as a dictionary or set,).. You can find its usage in the docs here:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len

Comment: The website example is really not a very good example of Python. 1) you don't need to take the length of a list since a negative offset does that for you, and 2) the list (being mutable) is not a `newList`, but is modifying the list in-place. Also, 3) the function name implies it will swap the whole list, but it only swaps first and last elements. You might want to reverse a list as an exercise, but the built-in list `reverse` method would normally be used.

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed them both for the time being.

Comment: @tripleee Could you please describe your answer more clearly?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. You had originally tagged this [tag:python-3.x] and [tag:python-2.7] but it cannot be about two incompatible versions of Python at the same time, so I edited your question to remove those tags. Python 3 is the currently supported version of the language so questions with only the [tag:python] tag tend to get Python 3 answers now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

len( ) function returns the size of a container, for lists it is implemented as returning number of objects within it.

Consequently `x[len(x)-a]` and `x[-a]` are equivalent, as long as `a` is smaller or equal to `len(x)`, and the two codes provided are functionally the same.

In terms of python style, the code you proposed is a more pythonic way than the one in the example you were provided.

Since the original code is a part of some "learn to python" tutorial author might prefer to be more explicit about what is going on, and thus opted for explicitly computing the length of the list. The way it is done in the tuorial example will also be more similar to how this code would look like in many other programming languages, thus for the learning purpose it might be a good choice.

As a cherry on top, the code could be further simplified to:

```
def swapList(x):
  x[0], x[-1] = x[-1], x[0]
  return x
```